# How do I reorganize my C# list around a different variable?

Tags: c#, list

I have a room full of students and I've already tracked which activity they've done and what score they achieved on each activity using this code:

```
public class TrackActivity
{
     public String StudentName {get; set;}
     public String ActivityName {get; set;}
     public int ActivityScore {get; set;}  // out of 10 points
}
```

I currently have a List of "TrackActivity", and would like to reorganize it so that it has a StudentName-centric organization.  That is, I would like to organize my data by StudentName, and then from there find out which ActivityName they've participated in and what their ActivityScore was.

For example, I know from my List of TrackActivity:

```
Barbara, juggling, 9
Barbara, cycling, 7
Chris, cycling, 9
Dennis, juggling, 8
Dennis, cycling, 6
Dennis, archery, 10
```

I would like to reorganize what I have so that I know the information this way instead:

```
Barbara, 2 activities: juggling (9), cycling (7)
Chris, 1 activity: cycling (9)
Dennis, 3 activities: juggling (8), cycling (6), archery (10)
```

I know how to output my List to a text file for viewing.  How can I output my List so that it's formatted like the latter?

Comment: Errrr, what have you tried? Do you have any code that might actually use this reorganized data structure? (That would point the way to how the structure might look.)

Downrating because this doesn't seem to be a complete question.

Comment: I guess my question is really this: How do I format my current List for output so that I can see the data the way I want to in a text file?  I know how to output to text, but I don't know how to reorganize what I've got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<TrackActivity> activities = new List<TrackActivity> {
    new TrackActivity { StudentName = "Barbara", ActivityName = "juggling", ActivityScore = 9 },
    new TrackActivity { StudentName = "Barbara", ActivityName = "cycling", ActivityScore = 7 },
    new TrackActivity { StudentName = "Chris", ActivityName = "cycling ", ActivityScore = 9 },
    new TrackActivity { StudentName = "Dennis", ActivityName = "juggling ", ActivityScore = 8 },
    new TrackActivity { StudentName = "Dennis", ActivityName = "cycling ", ActivityScore = 6 },
    new TrackActivity { StudentName = "Dennis", ActivityName = "archery ", ActivityScore = 10 },
};
foreach (var student in activities.GroupBy(a => a.StudentName))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} {2}: {3}",
                      student.Key,
                      student.Count(),
                      student.Count() > 1 ? "activities" : "activity",
                      string.Join(", ", student.Select(a => string.Format("{0} ({1})", a.ActivityName, a.ActivityScore)).ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: The error I got was: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @phan Do you use .Net 2.0/3.5? I added `.ToArray()` in the code.

Comment: Yes, thank you, adding .ToArray() solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

change your `List<TrackActivity>` to a `Dictionary<string, TrackActivity>`
then create a collection class that derives from  `Dictionary<string, TrackActivity>`

```
  public class TrackActivitys: dictionary<string, TrackActivity>
  {
      public void Add(string studentName, string activityName, int activityScore)
      {
           base.Add(studentName,
                   new TrackActivity(studentName, activityName, activityScore));
      }
      public TrackActivity this[string studentName]
      {
          get { return base[studentName]; }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to reorganize your code like this:

```
// Since your students will use very typical activities, why not have a separate class just for activity type?
public class Activity
{
    // Immutability is optional — I just tend to specify it by default.
    public readonly string Name;

    public Activity(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public readonly string Name;

    // It probably shouldn't be exposed like this
    public Dictionary<Activity, int> Scores = new Dictionary<Activity, int>();

    public Student(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
    }

    public string Report()
    {
        string result = Name;
        if (Scores != null && Scores.Count > 0)
        {
            result += ", " + Scores.Count + " activities: ";
            result += string.Join(", ", Scores.Select(s => c.Key.Name + "(" + c.Value + ")"));
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I don't have C# compiler at hand right now, so this can have one or two minor bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need two classes, a Student (who holds a list of Activities):

```
public class Student
{
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

And an activity class that holds the information:

```
public class Activity
{
   public String Name {get; set;}
   public int Score {get; set;}  // out of 10 points

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Score);
   }
}
```

The output would be something like:

```
foreach (Student s in students)
   Console.Writeline("{0}, {1} activities: {2}", s.Name, s.Activities.Count, String.Join(',', s.Activities.Select(a => a.ToString()).ToArray());
```

You could also separate "Activity" into its own class (separate from score) and use a dictionary to track them as suggested in other answers.

Comment: This way, you have a LOT of activity objects with duplicated names, and you won't be able to easily rename "PE" to "Physical education", for example.

Comment: @golergka, You are absolutely correct. I believe the OP's code would have this problem as well. You could fix the problem by having 3 classes, I'll edit to include that possibility.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, agree that the renaming issue is endemic to the approach anyway